# C, malloc size of

Tags: c, malloc

```
typedef struct _lnode{
    struct _lnode *next;
    size_t row;
    size_t column;
    short data;
}lnode;

typedef struct _matrix{

    size_t width;
    size_t height;
    size_t k;

    int **data;

}matrix;

matrix* make_matrix(size_t width, size_t height, size_t k){

    matrix *m= malloc(sizeof(matrix));
    //matrix *m= malloc(sizeof(*matrix)); DOES NOT WORK
    if(m==NULL) return NULL;

    m->width = width;
    m->height = height;

    /*
    Since m->data is a int **, it points to int *, 
    so I have to allocate a number of int *-sized objects to store in it.
    */
    m->data = malloc(sizeof(int *)*height);
    if(m->data == NULL){
        free(m);
        return NULL;
    }

    for(size_t i=0; i < height; i++){
        m->data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*width);
        if(m->data[i] == NULL){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) free(m->data[j]);
            free(m->data);
            free(m);
            return 0;
        }

        for(size_t j = 0; j < width; j++)
            m->data[i][j] = 0;
    }

    return m;
}


lnode* make_node(size_t row, size_t column, short data){
    lnode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));

    if(newNode==NULL) return NULL;

    newNode->row = row;
    newNode->column = column;
    newNode->data = data;

    return newNode;
}
```

These two functions work fine. In the make_matrix function, I first tried this

```
 matrix *m= malloc(sizeof(*matrix));
```

instead of

```
 matrix *m= malloc(sizeof(matrix));
```

Then it only works for the first iteration in the for loop and falls into the if statement

```
if(m->data[i] == NULL){
                for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) free(m->data[j]);
                free(m->data);
                free(m);
                return 0;
            }
```

I know that sizeof(pointer) will return a size of the pointer. In make_node function I am doing lnode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode)); and it worked fine. I am trying to do the same thing in make_matrix function. It doesn't work this time...

Comment: It works fine (as it should) with ` matrix *m= malloc(sizeof(matrix));`? If so, what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newNode` is a variable, so `sizeof *newnode` returns the size of thing it wants to point to.  The equivalent in `make_matrix()` would be `sizeof *m`, not `sizeof *matrix`.

Comment: I may just be tired, but I'm not even sure what `sizeof(*matrix)` means to the compiler.  `matrix` is a `typedef`, so `*matrix` shouldn't be meaningful (the correct syntax would be `(matrix *)`).

Answer (score 0):

You say "I know that sizeof(pointer) will return a size of the pointer"

But I don't think you do.

You need to do:

```
matrix *m = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
```

Otherwise you get 4 bytes (or 8, if your machine is using 64bit pointers).

"It works" with what you're doing is not correct. The behavior is undefined. You just got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are saying that your code fails because `m->data[i]` is not null?

`malloc` will not initialize your variable, the contents of what you get is unpredictable. Use `calloc` to initialize to all bits zero, or even better if you have a standard conforming compiler use something like

```
*m = (matrix){ 0 };
```

to initialize all fields to `0`.